# connectedComponents error on opencv 2.4.8

Tags: python, algorithm, opencv, watershed

I am using Watershed Algorithm for image segmentation (splitting foreground and background) and I get the following error:

AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'connectedComponents'

The algorithm can be found at: http://opencv-python-tutroals.readthedocs.org/en/latest/py_tutorials/py_imgproc/py_watershed/py_watershed.html#image-segmentation-with-watershed-algorithm where the issue is on connectedComponents. I am using openCv 2.4.8

I appreciate any help.

Comment: `connectedComponents` is available starting from OpenCV 3.0. You need to use `findContours` combined with `drawContours` for older versions

Comment: Thanks for the info.